# Remove border-bottom of TextFields on Android using NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

How do I remove the default border at the bottom of every TextField on Android using NativeScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bottom border is part of the Material Design Language and cannot be removed by setting the `border-bottom-width` property to 0. If you do so, or try to set the color to transparent, the border will still be there. Though it may seem redundant, it can be removed by **combining both properties**:

```css
TextField {
  border-bottom-width: 1;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

More information on this here: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2626#issuecomment-261493611

Comment: Thanks that helped. However in NativeScript 7.x, just setting `border-bottom-width: 0` seems to be sufficient.